# Quick 64-bit deterministic hash in python

Tags: python, hash, checksum

I have previously been using a `adler32` to produce a 32-bit hash of blocks of text (which i then use as a filename for saving a cache of the processed version of that text). e.g.

```
  hashed_file_name = adler32(pragraph.encode())
```

I am looking to increase the hash size, to reduce the likelihood of collisions [i.e. two different blocks of text getting the same hashed-code, which given I have around 10-million text bocks, i think would give a collisions in about 0.2% of cases - i.e. 10 million / 2^32 ]

My question is, what is the fastest hash generator which produces at least a  64-bit hash? Would sha1 be an efficient option [which produces a 160-bit hash]? i.e.

```
  hashed_file_name  = hashlib.sha1(pragraph.encode()).hexdigest()
```

While this is a over-kill for my neads, are other versions/options more efficient in terms of processing time?

Comment: Have a look at the [PyHash library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhash/0.6.2). It includes MurmurHash 3 (which has 32- and 128-bit variants) and Google's CityHash (which has 64- and 128-bit variants).

Comment: Here's a nice list.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions

Comment: Why not use python built-in hash() function? It generated 64-bit numbers on my 64 bit machine. I assume it is pretty fast.

Comment: `hash()` is 32 bits on a 32-bit Python, looks like, although this is an implementation detail that could change.

Comment: @kindall hash() will produce different values for every program run. Not very useful for checking files.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is 128bit, and doesn't add a dependency. It's probably fast enough, although you know your requirements better than I do. Another thought is to apply your 32-bit hash twice, after permuting the data, say by a XOR or rotation.